# Subquery resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a query below.  Is this the right way to do a subquery?

```
SELECT App.State_Pstl_Name,
       COUNT (DISTINCT App.APLCTN_ID) AS Total_APLCTN
FROM (Select count(distinct b.APLCTN_ID ),
             A.Aplctn_Sk,
             b.APLCTN_ID,
             A.Lctn_Sk,  
             b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT,
             B.Aplctn_Sbmtd_Dt,
             c.STATE_PSTL_CD,
             c.STATE_PSTL_NAME,
             C.Urbn_Rrl_Ind
      From  MIDAS.Ee_Application_Mmbr_Fact A,
            MIDAS.Insrnc_Aplctn_Dmnsn B,
            Midas.Lctn_Dmnsn C
      Where A.Lctn_Sk In (Select Lctn_Sk
                            From  Midas.Lctn_Dmnsn
                            Where Flag_Actv_Rec = 'Y' ) And
            A.Aplctn_Sk in (select Aplctn_Sk
                              from MIDAS.Insrnc_Aplctn_Dmnsn
                              Where Flag_Actv_Rec = 'Y' ) AND
            (b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT >= '01-JUL-13' OR
             b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT <= '01-JUL-31' ) 
     GROUP BY A.Aplctn_Sk,
              b.APLCTN_ID,
              a.LCTN_SK,
              b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT,
              B.Aplctn_Sbmtd_Dt,
              c.STATE_PSTL_CD,
              c.STATE_PSTL_NAME,
              c.URBN_RRL_IND) App
GROUP BY App.STATE_PSTL_NAME
Order By App.State_Pstl_Name
```

Comment: What do you mean " is this the right way to do subqry"?  Does the query work?  Are you having any problems?

Comment: what i meant was that i am using table names in subquery and also in from clause, and select is from the From clause table names, so is this correct way ?

Comment: Suggestion - use less white space. Putting nearly every keyword, column name, etc, on a separate line makes the code very difficult to read and comprehend.  White space is good - but like anything, too much is bad.

Comment: By the way - this is SQL, not PL/SQL. I changed the tag.

Comment: Regardless, this "b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT >= '01-JUL-13'" is the wrong way to do a date predicate. Use "b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT >= date '2013-01-01'" or "b.APLCTN_CREATD_DT >= to_date('01-JUL-13','DD-MON-RR')". Two-digit years are still not a good idea.

Comment: Could you please post your functional requirement in plain English so that we can review the code and check if it is fine?